# What does 'hopeful' mean when referring to tennis player?

Tags: meaning

I wonder what does the word *hopeful* mean in the following context

> After Agnieszka Radwanska defeated Belarusian hopeful Olga Govortsova in straight sets during the second round of the Australian Open.'

I guess that the phrase *to defeat sb in straight set* means *to win a game without losing a single set*. Am I right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may not be obvious, but *hopeful* is actually being used as a noun here rather than as an adjective;  the name that comes afterward states which "hopeful" was defeated, rather than being the noun to which an adjective is applied.

As seen at [theFreeDictionary.com](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/hopeful%E2%80%8E), *hopeful* when used as a noun in this manner means

> A person who aspires to success or who shows promise of succeeding

or

> a person considered to be on the brink of success

And yes, to win *in straight sets* means to win every set that was played.

Comment: Can I say "Govortsova was a hopeful in Australian Open but she fell in the second round.".

Answer (score 2):

Yes on the second count.  A *hopeful* is someone likely or hoping to succeed.

Answer (score 0):

In that [article](http://www.thenews.pl/1/5/Artykul/158791,Radwanska-wins-in-straight-sets), the author describes Govortsova as a "hopeful" because she is an underdog in the Australian Open tennis tournament. She is ranked #98 in the world, while Radwanska is ranked #5.

And yes, to win in straight sets means to win a match without losing a set.